# Include "against" or leave out?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is it correct to use against with mitigate as in this generic example?

> Since this risk type is rapidly evolving, our department is working to clarify the definition of (product) to mitigate **against** this exposure in the future.

The original did not include "against" but a reviewer (not a communications person) suggested the insertion.

Comment: Personally I would not add the 'against' as it confuses the statement, mitigate is 'to lessen' therefore 'to lessen against the exposure'. Drop the 'against' and it will read just fine

Comment: _Mitigate against_ is a confusion with _militate against_.

Comment: I always took "mitigate against"  as a confusion of "hedge against".  To mitigate the problem one reduces *the problem*. When one hedges against a problem, they work to minimize the *effects* or protect themselves from the problem, but they don't really reduce the problem itself.

Answer (score 3):

The use of `against` here doesn't add much to the meaning of the sentence.

[The usage, as per Google NGrams, seems to agree.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20mitigate%20the%2C%20to%20mitigate%20against&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20mitigate%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20mitigate%20against%3B%2Cc0)

I'd leave it out.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't even aware of this tool. One learns something new every day!

Answer (score 2):

"Mitigate against" is generally not accepted as proper usage. You should just use "mitigate".

**mitigate against** *Usage Problem*

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mitigate3

***Incorrect:***    Dramatic action is required to mitigate against the devastating consequences of climate change.

***Correct:***  Dramatic action is required to mitigate the devastating consequences of climate change.

http://aimpublishing.com/aimpub/word-usage/mitigate-mitigate-against

Answer (score 1):

As John Lawler notes in a comment above, the impetus to add *against* after *mitigate* comes from confusion of *mitigate* for *militate*. The meanings of the two words aren't especially similar. Here is the entry for *mitigate* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **mitigate** *vt* (15c) **1 :** to cause to become less harsh or hostile : MOLLIFY {aggressiveness may be *mitigated* or ... channeled —Ashley Montagu} **2 a :** to make less severe or painful : ALLEVIATE  **b :** EXTENUATE

And here is the corresponding entry for *militate*:

> **militate** *vi* (ca. 1600) **:** to have weight or effect {his boyish appearance *militated* against his getting an early promotion}

As you can see, the *militate* example is followed by *against*. In contrast, the *mitigate* example (for definition 1 of that term) doesn't follow *mitigate* with *against*, and in fact the example would sound quite bad with that addition. Moreover, none of the three single-word synonyms given for *mitigate* (namely, *mollify*, *alleviate*, and *extenuate*) is ever paired with *against* either.

Notwithstanding all of these points, the *Eleventh Collegiate* offers the following rather tendentious usage note regarding "mitigate against":

> ***usage*** *Mitigate* is sometimes used as an intransitive (followed by *against*) where *militate* might be expected. Even though Faulkner used it {some intangible and invisible social force that *mitigates* against him —William Faulkner} and one critic thinks it should be called an American idiom, it is usu. considered a mistake.

In my opinion, the reason it is usu. considered a mistake is because it usu. *is* a mistake—including in the instance penned by the Olympian William Faulkner.

In the OP's example—

> Since this risk type is rapidly evolving, our department is working to clarify the definition of (product) to mitigate [against] this exposure in the future.

—the sense of *mitigate* is probably the *Eleventh Collegiate*'s definition 2(a) ("ALLEVIATE"). I see no reason whatsoever to add *against* after *mitigate*; nor can I find any rational basis for replacing *mitigate* with *militate against*. I recommend discarding the "American idiom" that your reviewer introduced and sticking with *mitigate* in its simple, unadorned, and correct form.

Comment: In a 2009 survey involving an [AHD usage panel](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mitigate+against#:~:text=mitigate%20against%20Usage%20Problem,something), sizeable / very sizeable minorities (30% / 44%) _did not reject_ different 'mitigate against' usages ('His relative youth might mitigate against him in a national election.' // 'What steps can the town take to mitigate against damage from coastal storms?')

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm not sure whether that change in usage vitiates against my argument of eight years ago or alleviates against it.

Comment: Different usage panels don't always concur ... but I'd say that 'mitigate against' is mumpsimising.

Answer (score -1):

The use of "against" in conjuction with "mitigate", i.e. "mitigate against", is absolutely incorrect. Since mitigate used alone indicates  the lessening of the effects of something injurious, bad or unwanted the use of against is superfluous.
This morning on BBC News someone who is a communications person committed this error. There was a time in the UK when the BBC was considered to be the bastion of correct English usage. That is no longer the case, it seems.

Comment: Hi Mab, this doesn't add anything new to the existing answers. Please go through those before answering. Please also take our [Tour] to get an idea of how this platform works. Welcome to ELU!

Comment: Joachim, are you telling me off?
I threw in my pennyworth because of the inclusion of "usually incorrect" in one comment which may suggest to some that there could be occasions when "mitigate against" would be considered correct.
I wanted to convey that the construction "militate against" is always absolutely incorrect.

Comment: I'm not doing anything of the sort (my "welcome" should have suggested that :). I'm just saying that this adds very little to the existing answers, and that as such it is a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your welcome and I will take the tour.

Comment: Enough said. Thank you for welcoming me and I will endeavour to follow procedure.

Comment: Hello. Mab. There are strong arguments that idiomaticity trumps redundancy ('neat and tidy', 'nook and cranny', 'bits and pieces' ...) when it comes to judging correctness. Would you say that 'appeal against' should be abandoned as 'appeal' does the same job? Similar cases are: 'brush [against] someone's leg.' 'Fight [against/with] the Elbonians.' 'Boo [at] the Elbonian team.' 'Check [on] the condition of the brakes.' 'Distinguish [between] similar outcomes.' 'Cross [over] the Forth Bridge.' 'Mourn [for] his lost children....'